Make Java class Indexable?
I've been using Java for a little bit and decided to take up the task of recreating Tetris. I want to make a custom class to manage the grid. That code looks a bit like this:
public class GridPanel {
    private int[][] grid;
    public int rows;
    public int cols;

    public GridPanel(int rows, int columns) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = columns;
        this.grid = new int[rows][columns];
    }

    public boolean isRowEmpty(int row) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.grid[row].length; i++) {
            if (this.grid[row][i] > 0) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

There's a bit more but you get the general idea. It was around here that I began wondering about if there was a way I could index this class directly. Is there a trait or something that can be implemented in order to index it?
(Sort of like Rust or C#, examples below)
struct GridPanel<T: Clone> {
    grid: Vec<Vec<T>>,
    rows: usize,
    cols: usize
}

impl<T> Index<I> for GridPanel<T: Clone> {// apologies, I'm not very familiar with Rust
    type Output = T::Output;

    fn index(&self, i: usize, j: usize) -> T {
        return self.grid[i][j];
    }
}

public class GridPanel {
    private int[][] grid;
    public int rows;
    public int cols;
    public int this[int row, int column] {
        get => grid[row][column];
        set => grid[row][column] = value;
    }
}


No. Mainly because Java does not allow operator overloading.

Alright, thanks!
